# phpMyAdmin in a production environment

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am learning `php` whilst building a small web application that uses the phpMyAdmin utility to manage `mySQL` database queries in a development environment.

I am wondering if this tool can be used to administer and handle `mySQL` in a full production environment when I hopefully go live with my completed application.

I have looked around for answers online without getting much in the way of clarification.

Comment: it *can* be used of course, whether it should be is a matter of opinion. computer programs don't know the difference between "development" and "production".

Comment: So it can be but it is not really advisable ?. Appreciate your steering

Comment: The difference between "development" and "production" can be very hazy, especially if people "develop" on their production server. A more formal split is something I'd encourage as hot-patching code on your server is not a sustainable development model.

Comment: My advice: Stay *away* from "tutorials", especially the low-quality garbage floating around on YouTube. Consider using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) to solve problems like this. These give you patterns to follow for organizing your code into proper model, view and controller contexts and avoids ending up with confused concerns, with HTML, PHP, SQL, and JavaScript all jumbled together. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: These also offer database migration tools that help manage changes on your development machine and give you a way to reliably replicate them on your production server. This is one of the biggest benefits to using proper tools.

Comment: @tadman noted with thanks, il be mindful off that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely can be used.

Some would argue that it shouldn't be used in production, however. The main reason being for security. At worst, phpMyAdmin could be a completely unprotected way for attackers to access your database. At best, it's something extraneous that's not strictly necessary in a production environment.

Considering that you're just learning php, I wouldn't worry to much about using it in production. Just put a password on it.